# Justifying taking Fourier transform of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am prearing for my final exams and came across this question in the archives. [Here](https://math.ucsd.edu/sites/math.ucsd.edu/files/grad/qualifying-exams/real-analysis-math240/SP13_240_Real_Analysis_Qual.pdf) is a link for the same to highlight that this is a past exam problem and not a HW.

---

[image]

---

**Attempt**

Taking the fourier transform of $$- \Delta u+ u=f$$ yields $$4 \pi^2 |z|^2\hat{u}(z)+\hat{u}(z)=\hat{f}(z)$$ thus giving us $(a)$. But how do I justify taking the Fourier transform of derivatives?

My reference book is Folland. Theorem $8.22(e)$ says that for $f \in L^1$,

[image]

Clearly the hypthesis in $(e)$ are not met. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Existence of partial derivatives, pointwise, on it's own (with no assumption like absolute continuity, or similar) almost never plays well. My guess is they either missed a continuity of derivatives assumption (so that you can use Folland's result), or they're taking derivatives in the distributional/weak sense.

Comment: @Jose27 I think so too. Any insights on part (b)?

Comment: I think part (b) is just taking the inverse FT of the identity part (a), replacing the denominator with the identity given and using Fubini to switch the order of integration.